# pandas groupby by customized year, e.g. a school year

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, offset

In a pandas data frame I would like to find the mean values of a column, grouped by a 'customized' year.

An example would be to compute the mean values of school marks for a school year (e.g. Sep/YYYY to Aug/YYYY+1).
The pandas docs gives some information on offsets and business year etc., but I can't really make any sense out of that to get a working example.

Here is a minimal example where mean values of school marks are computed per year (Jan-Dec), which is what I **do not want**.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(low=1, high=5, size=36),
            index=pd.date_range('2001-09-01', freq='M', periods=36),
            columns=['marks'])

df_yearly = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="A")).mean()
```

This could yield e.g.:

```
print(df):
            marks
2001-09-30      1
2001-10-31      4
2001-11-30      2
2001-12-31      1
2002-01-31      4
2002-02-28      1
2002-03-31      2
2002-04-30      1
2002-05-31      3
2002-06-30      3
2002-07-31      3
2002-08-31      3
2002-09-30      4
2002-10-31      1
...
2003-11-30      4
2003-12-31      2
2004-01-31      1
2004-02-29      2
2004-03-31      1
2004-04-30      3
2004-05-31      4
2004-06-30      2
2004-07-31      2
2004-08-31      4

print(df_yearly):

          marks
2001-12-31  2.000000
2002-12-31  2.583333
2003-12-31  2.666667
2004-12-31  2.375000
```

My desired output would correspond to something like:

```
2001-09/2002-08 mean_value
2002-09/2003-08 mean_value
2003-09/2004-08 mean_value
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Wow, many thanks to all of you! Amazed by your speed of solving this issue! I'll mark the answer of Quang Hoang as the accepted one, as it contains the 'Q-AUG' fiscal year information - which I found in the docs, but couldn't get running. Thanks to all though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can manually compute the school years:

```
# if month>=9 we move it to the next year
school_years = df.index.year + (df.index.month>8).astype(int)
```

Another option is to use fiscal year starting from September:

```
school_years = df.index.to_period('Q-AUG').qyear
```

And we can groupby:

```
df.groupby(school_years).mean()
```

Output:

```
         marks
2002  2.333333
2003  2.500000
2004  2.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

One more approach

```
a = (df.index.month == 9).cumsum()
val = df.groupby(a, sort=False)['marks'].mean().reset_index()
dates = df.index.to_series().groupby(a, sort=False).agg(['first', 'last']).reset_index()
dates.merge(val, on='index')
```

**Output**

```
  index     first         last  marks
0   1   2001-09-30  2002-08-31  2.750000
1   2   2002-09-30  2003-08-31  2.333333
2   3   2003-09-30  2004-08-31  2.083333
```

Comment: Interesting how you and I got the same logic but got different outputs. Also `(df.index.month == 9).cumsum()` would work without `np.where`.

Comment: Yes. I think our output's are different because of `np.random.randint` used to generate the data-set (no `seed` is specified). Thanks for the tip on `cumsum`, I was not aware of that.