# Change yearly ordered dataframe to seasonly orderd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, shift

In Pandas, I would like to create columns, which will represent the season (e.g. travel season) starting from November and ending in October next year.

This is my snippet:

```
from numpy import random
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('1990-01-01', freq='M', periods=12),
    'travel_2016': random.randint(10, size=(12)),
    'travel_2017': random.randint(10, size=(12)),
    'travel_2018': random.randint(10, size=(12)),
    'travel_2019': random.randint(10, size=(12)),
    'travel_2020': random.randint(10, size=(12))})

    df['month_date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%m')
    df = df.drop(columns = ['date'])
```

I was trying this approach [pandas groupby by customized year, e.g. a school year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60545752/pandas-groupby-by-customized-year-e-g-a-school-year)
I failed after 'unpivoting' the table with both solutions. It would be easier for me to keep up the pivot table for future operations.

My desired output would be something like this:

```
    season_2016/2017 season_2017/2018 season_2018/2019 season_2019/2020 month_date
0   8                7                7                4                11
1   0                1                4                8                12
2   1                4                5                9                01
3   8                3                5                7                02
4   4                7                8                3                03
5   6                8                4                4                04
6   5                8                3                1                05
7   7                0                1                1                06
8   1                2                1                3                07
9   8                9                7                5                08
10  7                7                7                8                09
11  9                1                4                0                10
```

Many thanks!

Comment: are the values in expected dataframe based on the input dataframe or made up? could you explain the logic behind 1 season?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is already foramtted as you want, roughly: you’re basically shifting all the rows down by 2, and getting the 2 bottom rows up to the start − but shifted into the next year.

```
>>> year_ends = df.shift(-10)
>>> year_ends = year_ends.drop(columns=['month_date']).shift(axis='columns').join(year_ends['month_date'])
>>> year_ends
    travel_2016  travel_2017  travel_2018  travel_2019  travel_2020 month_date
0           NaN          7.0          8.0          3.0          2.0         11
1           NaN          6.0          9.0          3.0          7.0         12
2           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN
3           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN
4           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN
5           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN
6           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN
7           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN
8           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN
9           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN
10          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN
11          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN
```

The rest is pretty easy:

```
>>> seasons = df.shift(2).fillna(year_ends)
>>> seasons
    travel_2016  travel_2017  travel_2018  travel_2019  travel_2020 month_date
0           NaN          7.0          8.0          3.0          2.0         11
1           NaN          6.0          9.0          3.0          7.0         12
2           5.0          8.0          4.0          3.0          2.0         01
3           0.0          8.0          3.0          7.0          0.0         02
4           3.0          1.0          0.0          0.0          0.0         03
5           3.0          6.0          3.0          1.0          4.0         04
6           7.0          7.0          5.0          9.0          5.0         05
7           9.0          7.0          0.0          9.0          5.0         06
8           3.0          8.0          2.0          0.0          6.0         07
9           5.0          1.0          3.0          4.0          8.0         08
10          2.0          5.0          8.0          7.0          4.0         09
11          4.0          9.0          1.0          3.0          1.0         10
```

Of course you should now rename the columns appropriately:

```
>>> seasons.rename(columns=lambda c: c if not c.startswith('travel_') else f"season_{int(c[7:]) - 1}/{c[7:]}")
    season_2015/2016  season_2016/2017  season_2017/2018  season_2018/2019  season_2019/2020 month_date
0                NaN               7.0               8.0               3.0               2.0         11
1                NaN               6.0               9.0               3.0               7.0         12
2                5.0               8.0               4.0               3.0               2.0         01
3                0.0               8.0               3.0               7.0               0.0         02
4                3.0               1.0               0.0               0.0               0.0         03
5                3.0               6.0               3.0               1.0               4.0         04
6                7.0               7.0               5.0               9.0               5.0         05
7                9.0               7.0               0.0               9.0               5.0         06
8                3.0               8.0               2.0               0.0               6.0         07
9                5.0               1.0               3.0               4.0               8.0         08
10               2.0               5.0               8.0               7.0               4.0         09
11               4.0               9.0               1.0               3.0               1.0         10
```

Note that the 2 first values of 2015 are NaN, which makes sense, as those were not in the initial dataframe.

---

An alternate way is to use datetime tools. This may be more generic:

```
>>> data = df.set_index('month_date').rename_axis('year', axis='columns').stack().reset_index(name='data')
>>> data.head()
  month_date         year  data
0         01  travel_2016     5
1         01  travel_2017     8
2         01  travel_2018     4
3         01  travel_2019     3
4         01  travel_2020     2
>>> dates = data['year'].str[7:].str.cat(data['month_date']).transform(pd.to_datetime, format='%Y%m')
>>> dates.head()
0   2016-01-01
1   2017-01-01
2   2018-01-01
3   2019-01-01
4   2020-01-01
Name: year, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Then as in the linked question get the year fiscal year starting in november:

```
>>> season = dates.dt.to_period('Q-OCT').dt.qyear.rename('season')
>>> seasonal_data = data.join(season).pivot('month_date', 'season', 'data')
>>> seasonal_data.rename(columns=lambda c: f"season_{c - 1}/{c}", inplace=True)
>>> seasonal_data.reindex([*df['month_date'][-2:], *df['month_date'][:-2]]).reset_index()
season month_date  season_2015/2016  season_2016/2017  season_2017/2018  season_2018/2019  season_2019/2020  season_2020/2021
0              11               NaN               7.0               8.0               3.0               2.0               4.0
1              12               NaN               6.0               9.0               3.0               7.0               9.0
2              01               5.0               8.0               4.0               3.0               2.0               NaN
3              02               0.0               8.0               3.0               7.0               0.0               NaN
4              03               3.0               1.0               0.0               0.0               0.0               NaN
5              04               3.0               6.0               3.0               1.0               4.0               NaN
6              05               7.0               7.0               5.0               9.0               5.0               NaN
7              06               9.0               7.0               0.0               9.0               5.0               NaN
8              07               3.0               8.0               2.0               0.0               6.0               NaN
9              08               5.0               1.0               3.0               4.0               8.0               NaN
10             09               2.0               5.0               8.0               7.0               4.0               NaN
11             10               4.0               9.0               1.0               3.0               1.0               NaN
```