# Convert calendar year columns (Jan-Dec) to financial year columns (Jul-Jun) in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is a simplified DataFrame, with calendar year columns (Jan-Dec) & associated 202X_value columns. In my actual DataFrame, the 202X_value values could be anything, not necessarily 1-12.

```
   2020 2020_value 2021 2021_value 2022 2022_value
0  Jan  1          Jan  1          Jan  1
1  Feb  2          Feb  2          Feb  2
2  Mar  3          Mar  3          Mar  3
...
10 Nov 11          Nov  11         Nov  11
11 Dec 12          Dec  12         Dec  12
```

How can I convert these calendar year columns to financial year columns, like the DataFrame below?
*Note the 202X_value column values need to remain adjacent to the corresponding months.

```
   20-21 20-21_value 21-22 21-22_value 22-23 22-23_value
0  Jul   7           Jul   7           Jul   7
1  Aug   8           Aug   8           Aug   8
2  Sep   9           Sep   9           Sep   9
...
10 May   5           May   5           May   5
11 Jun   6           Jun   6           Jun   6
```

*Note that 2020 Jan-Jun data will be lost (as the 20-21 column's first row is Jul) and 2023 Jan-Jun won't exist (NaN).

I have attempted to use parts of the solutions in the SO questions below to no avail:

[How do I shift multiple columns? Pandas, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47490505/how-do-i-shift-multiple-columns-pandas-python)

[Change yearly ordered dataframe to seasonly orderd dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68024200/change-yearly-ordered-dataframe-to-seasonly-orderd-dataframe?noredirect=1&lq=1) - this solution works if you are only moving 202X columns, but not when you also have associated 202X_value columns.

Comment: please post what you expect the outcome to look like so that users can help you achieve this...

Comment: @D.L the desired outcome is shown in the 2nd code block...

Answer (score 0):

The last [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68024496/18571565) you provided does work as a solution, but just requires a column shift of 2 rather than 1:

```py
# year ends
year_ends = df.shift(-6)  # shift by 6 here so that Jul is first
year_ends = year_ends.shift(2, axis='columns')  # shift two rows across

# financial years
fin_year = df.shift(6).fillna(year_ends)  # fill start with year_ends
# rename columns
fin_year.columns = [f"{yy}-{int(yy)+1}{v}"
                    for yy, v in zip(fin_year.columns.str[2:4],
                                     fin_year.columns.str[4:])]
```